# Hyper terminal hangs when I open a project folder in atom using atom . or atom -n <folder> commands

Tags: command-line, atom-editor, project-folder

I used the hyper terminal to open my project folder in Atom. The commands I tried were `atom .` and `atom -n <folder>`.The command was executed and the folder opened in Atom, but both of these methods led to my terminal hanging.
I tried using Ctrl + C to exit the command, but it didn't help. I had to restart the terminal to finally exit the ongoing command. Is there any other way I can open project folders in Atom using the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

you change your user name. So the atom path is still with the older name. You need to mutch it .

You can simply do this by opening the run dialog (win + r), type "SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe" and hit enter. Here you should select "Environment Variables..." and edit the Path for your user (because atom is probably installed only for you).